How to attach end of 2x4 to narrow 1.5" side of 2x4?
I'm building some Spruce 2x4 + MDF garage shelves that are width constrained. I need every inch I can get. So, rather than put 3.5" wide upright 2x4s on the front and back of the shelving, I'd like to have the 1.5" wide side of the 2x4s on the ends of the shelving. That'll save me 1.5" at each end, which overall gives me the extra 3" I need in order to be able to fit the garbage can, compost bin, and 2 recycling bins under the shelves, which will free up a big chunk of floor space.
My question is, do I need horizontal 2x4s connecting the front 2x4 uprights to the back ones? or is screwing the uprights to the 3 shelves (each of which consists of a horizontal 2x4 frame with MDF on top) enough?
If I do need horizontal pieces, then I'll need to attach the ends of them to the narrow-sides of the uprights. How can I attach the horizontal pieces securely, so the shelving can carry a lot of weight? 4.5" screws or nails doesn't seem like the right solution. Pocket holes don't seem sturdy enough. Same for toe-nailing, and mounting L-brackets under that cross-piece. I'm at a loss, but I'm also new to framing, joinery, etc.

For your shelving project, attaching the narrow (1.5") side of a 2x4 securely to another 2x4 can be a bit tricky, especially if you want the structure to be robust and capable of carrying a lot of weight. Here's what I think may work. Also, I took a long time to type this out in detail for you, so please share the picture of final product once its ready :)

Using Horizontal Bracing:

Install Horizontal Braces: You will need horizontal braces to connect the front and back 2x4 uprights. This adds lateral stability and helps distribute the load evenly across the entire shelving unit.
Attachment Method:

Half-Lap Joint: This is a strong and effective way to connect two pieces of wood at right angles. You'll need to cut half the thickness of each piece where they meet so that they overlap and create a flush joint. This increases the surface area for attaching the screws and helps resist shear forces.
Screws with Pilot Holes: Drill pilot holes before driving screws to prevent splitting the wood. Use screws that are long enough to penetrate deep into the wood without coming out the other side, such as 3.5” to 4” screws.
Wood Glue: Adding wood glue to the joint will increase the bond strength and prevent any potential loosening over time.




Alternatives to Horizontal Braces:

If you're tight on space and want to avoid horizontal braces, you could increase the number of screws attaching the 2x4 uprights to the shelves themselves. However, this is less ideal in terms of structural integrity, especially under heavy loads.


Securing Horizontals to Narrow-Sides:

Pocket Hole Joinery: While you mentioned concerns about pocket holes, they can be strong if used correctly. Use a high-quality pocket hole jig and screws designed for the purpose, making sure the holes are on the inside or underside to maintain the aesthetic of the piece.
Flat Steel Brackets: These can be placed on the inside of the corners where the horizontals meet the verticals. Use lag bolts to secure the brackets. The brackets help by providing additional shear strength.


Vertical Load-Bearing:

Since your shelving needs to carry weight, you should ensure that the load is directly transferred to the ground through the uprights. Avoid relying solely on the screws to hold weight—this is where the half-lap joint and proper bracing come in handy.


Final Check:

Make sure everything is square during assembly to avoid any stress on the joints. Consider reinforcing the frame with diagonal braces or gussets at the corners if needed for additional strength.



In summary, using horizontal braces with half-lap joints or strong pocket hole joinery will give you the most secure and stable solution. Make sure to pre-drill your holes and use wood glue to enhance the strength of the connections.

Wow, thanks for typing all of that! I've never done half-lap joints, but they do sound like the best choice here. I guess it's time to learn how! I'm gonna have to sharpen my chisels and slap a new blade on the multi-tool.

My only concern is that half-lapping a sideways 2x4 means each piece will be just 0.75" thick and 1.75" wide at the lap. Not much.


My question is, do I need horizontal 2x4s connecting the front 2x4 uprights to the back ones?

There's some personal interpretation in this, as we can already see, but my judgement is that no, you don't. Details of the build will be important however.
As currently planned you've got tons of what in effect is inbuilt 'bracing', the shelf assemblies. And you're firmly fixing each in place with plenty of screws. That's already a recipe for stability.
Details
How well this'll work depends on how uniformly cut the components are and how well you screw the thing together. In short, build this well and I think you're golden.

Fix the MDF tops to their frames rather than have them floating, as this builds in absolute rigidity — each shelf is in effect a basic torsion box in case you didn't realise. You don't need to glue if you use enough fasteners; you don't need the fasteners if you use glue.

Assemble the shelf boxes on the flattest surface you can arrange, even if that's just a sheet of plywood on a floor inside the house. Note I say flattest; it doesn't have to be level (although both flat and level would be ideal).

Make sure you correctly drill your pilot holes. This is standard advice for all regular screws but especially important for any screw that goes into end grain, where you lose approximately 25% holding power, see Endgrain screw withdrawal force. (Yes, this is much more hold than is commonly believed or assumed.)

Use the longest screw possible for each location. If you don't mind the extra expense go thicker as well — longer, beefier, screws can hold better than even a larger number of shorter, skinnier, screws.


Build square, then account for the floor
Expect to have to shim to get this to sit level as, unless you're extremely lucky, you can bet your floor is neither level nor dead flat. Maybe both :-)

Thank you for your mention of the shelf being a torsion box, and that you lose holding power when screwing into the end grain.

Welcome! Just to emphasise, you lose a little holding power. ~25% is often nothing to worry about, but where strength is paramount it can be compensated for easily in the ways mentioned.
